# Get all possible combinations from array elements with efficient way

Tags: sql, postgresql, combinations, postgresql-9.6

There is array with maximum 5 elements in it, for example given: `{1,2,3,4,5}`, I need get all possible unique combinations from this array, expected result is:

```
 {1}
 {1,2}
 {1,2,3}
 {1,2,3,4}
 {1,2,3,4,5}
 {1,2,3,5}
 {1,2,4}
 {1,2,4,5}
 {1,2,5}
 {1,3}
 {1,3,4}
 {1,3,4,5}
 {1,3,5}
 {1,4}
 {1,4,5}
 {1,5}
 {2}
 {2,3}
 {2,3,4}
 {2,3,4,5}
 {2,3,5}
 {2,4}
 {2,4,5}
 {2,5}
 {3}
 {3,4}
 {3,4,5}
 {3,5}
 {4}
 {4,5}
 {5}
```

I have this solution:

```
create table temp_all_possible_cards (
    card_ids int[]
);

create or replace function test(cards_in_hands INT[] )
returns void
as $$
begin 
    with all_possible_cards(ids) as(
        select ARRAY_APPEND('{}'::int[], t1.card_ids)||ARRAY_APPEND('{}'::int[], t2.card_ids)||ARRAY_APPEND('{}'::int[], t3.card_ids)||ARRAY_APPEND('{}'::int[], t4.card_ids)||ARRAY_APPEND('{}'::int[], t5.card_ids)
        from (
            select unnest(cards_in_hands) as card_ids
        ) t1
        cross join (
            select unnest(cards_in_hands) as card_ids
        ) t2
        cross join (
            select unnest(cards_in_hands) as card_ids
        ) t3
        cross join (
            select unnest(cards_in_hands) as card_ids
        ) t4
        cross join (
            select unnest(cards_in_hands) as card_ids
        ) t5
    )
    INSERT INTO temp_all_possible_cards
    SELECT DISTINCT uniq( sort(ids) ) from all_possible_cards;  
end;
$$ language plpgsql
```

This works, but there is one big problem, sometimes I need run this function 5000 times

```
do $$
begin
    for i in 1..5000 loop
        perform test('{1,2,3,4,5}');
    end loop;
end;
$$ language plpgsql
```

and execution time for loop is 55-60 second.

Question: How can I get all possible unique combinations from array with efficient way? How to optimise this solution, so that even 5000 times calling was significant fast than 60 second?

Comment: Hmm, I guess your cross join approach is already a good one for this problem though I'm not sure I the insert in the temp table is necessary and that can maybe done as an SQL function instead of a plPgsql one. But if the number of possible inputs is finite, you could pre-calculate and persist the results in a table. So later you'd only have to select the records matching the given input.

Answer (score 1):

```
;WITH NOS AS (SELECT 1 aval 
             UNION ALL
             SELECT aval + 1 FROM NOS WHERE aval < 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 - 1
             )
    SELECT LEFT(IQ.x, LEN(IQ.x) - 1) + '}' FROM (
            SELECT RTRIM('{' 
                                + CASE WHEN aval & 1 != 0 THEN '1, ' ELSE '' END        
                                + CASE WHEN aval & 2 != 0 THEN '2, ' ELSE '' END        
                                + CASE WHEN aval & 4 != 0 THEN '3, ' ELSE '' END        
                                + CASE WHEN aval & 8 != 0 THEN '4, ' ELSE '' END        
                                + CASE WHEN aval & 16 != 0 THEN '5, ' ELSE '' END) AS X     
                        FROM NOS) IQ
```

to show a benchmark

```
create table #test (x nvarchar(50))

declare @i int = 0; 

    declare @s datetime2 = sysutcdatetime();

    while @i < 5000
    begin

    ;WITH NOS AS (SELECT 1 aval 
                 UNION ALL
                 SELECT aval + 1 FROM NOS WHERE aval < 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 - 1
                 )
        insert #test SELECT LEFT(IQ.x, LEN(IQ.x) - 1) + '}' FROM (
                SELECT RTRIM('{' 
                                    + CASE WHEN aval & 1 != 0 THEN '1, ' ELSE '' END        
                                    + CASE WHEN aval & 2 != 0 THEN '2, ' ELSE '' END        
                                    + CASE WHEN aval & 4 != 0 THEN '3, ' ELSE '' END        
                                    + CASE WHEN aval & 8 != 0 THEN '4, ' ELSE '' END        
                                    + CASE WHEN aval & 16 != 0 THEN '5, ' ELSE '' END) AS X     
                            FROM NOS) IQ


        set @i = @i + 1;

        end 

        DECLARe @usTiming BIGINT = datediff(MICROSECOND, @s ,sysutcdatetime())

        select CAST(@usTiming as nvarchar(19)) + 'us = ' + CAST(CAST(@usTiming/1000000.000000000000 as dec(10,3)) as nvarchar(20)) + ' seconds';

        drop table #test
```

I got 2.5 seconds

Comment: sorry, I just noticed you are using postgresql - but the bitwise operator idea may still work for you

Comment: The NOS part could be achieved by populating a table, if you do not have WITH

Comment: Nice, I will modified this for postgres, just `2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 - 1` this "formula" always works? for `X`  count of elements, `2 *  X times - 1` always gives unique combinations count?

Comment: it works via binary, so for 5 items no selections is 00000 and all selected is 11111.  You actually start with 00001.  The 'binary' count from 1 to 31, gives all on/off combinations.  If you had 10 items then you would need to use 10 binary digits (max value 1023).  The & operator just finds out if a binary digit is there

Comment: And to generate a series of 1 - 32 in PostgreSQL - what's wrong with `generate_series` - much better than a recursive SQL!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) in a `plpython` function:

```
create or replace function generate_combinations(cards_in_hand int[])
returns void language plpython3u as $$

import itertools

plan = plpy.prepare("insert into temp_all_possible_cards values ($1)", ["int[]"])

for r in range(1, len(cards_in_hand) + 1):
    for i in itertools.combinations(cards_in_hand, r):
        plpy.execute(plan, [i])
$$;
```

This should be several times faster than the plpgsql function.

Answer (score 0):

This solution takes circa 1.5s for 5000 integer arrays (my test data table contains 5000 distinct arrays with length between 1 and 5, each element value is between 1 and 150)

The idea is to generate all possible binary values from 1 to length(array). Then I just have to take the element from the array where a 1 exists in the corresponding binary string.

A Getting the test data

B Generating the binary value. Because the `bin(5)` cast take no variable length I needed the substring function to normalize the bit value length to the array length.

C Unnesting the binary value next to the corresponding array values. Now I can filter out the array elements which shouldn't be in the combined result.

D Reaggregate the filtered elements.

```
SELECT 
    orig, 
    array_agg(single_char) -- D
FROM ( 
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT
            no,
            orig,
            unnest(regexp_split_to_array(no, '')) ::BOOLEAN AS to_set, -- C
            unnest(orig)         AS single_char
        FROM (
            SELECT
                substring(generate_series(1,(2^len_a - 1) ::INTEGER)::bit(5)::text, 5 - len_a + 1, 5) AS no, --B
                s.a AS orig
            FROM (                   
                SELECT 
                    s.a, 
                    array_length(s.a, 1) as len_a 
                FROM (
                    SELECT arrays::int[] a FROM testdata.arrays ORDER BY a -- A
                ) s               
            ) s
        ) s
    ) s
    WHERE
        to_set
    AND single_char IS NOT NULL
) s
GROUP BY orig, no
```

Example:

Table testdata contains

```
{1}
{1,1,118}
{1,2,70,142,11}
```

Result of the query is

```
orig                  array_agg             
--------------------  --------------------  
{1}                   {1}                   
{1,1,118}             {118}                 
{1,1,118}             {1}                   
{1,1,118}             {1,118}               
{1,1,118}             {1}                   
{1,1,118}             {118,1}               
{1,1,118}             {1,1}                 
{1,1,118}             {1,1,118}             
{1,2,70,142,11}       {11}                  
{1,2,70,142,11}       {142}                 
{1,2,70,142,11}       {142,11}              
{1,2,70,142,11}       {70}                  
{1,2,70,142,11}       {70,11}               
{1,2,70,142,11}       {70,142}              
{1,2,70,142,11}       {70,142,11}           
{1,2,70,142,11}       {2}                   
{1,2,70,142,11}       {2,11}                
{1,2,70,142,11}       {2,142}               
{1,2,70,142,11}       {142,11,2}            
{1,2,70,142,11}       {2,70}                
{1,2,70,142,11}       {2,70,11}             
{1,2,70,142,11}       {2,70,142}            
{1,2,70,142,11}       {2,70,142,11}         
{1,2,70,142,11}       {1}                   
{1,2,70,142,11}       {1,11}                
{1,2,70,142,11}       {1,142}               
{1,2,70,142,11}       {1,142,11}            
{1,2,70,142,11}       {1,70}                
{1,2,70,142,11}       {1,70,11}             
{1,2,70,142,11}       {1,70,142}            
{1,2,70,142,11}       {142,11,1,70}         
{1,2,70,142,11}       {1,2}                 
{1,2,70,142,11}       {1,2,11}              
{1,2,70,142,11}       {1,2,142}             
{1,2,70,142,11}       {1,2,142,11}          
{1,2,70,142,11}       {1,2,70}              
{1,2,70,142,11}       {1,2,70,11}           
{1,2,70,142,11}       {1,2,70,142}          
{1,2,70,142,11}       {1,2,70,142,11}
```

EDIT: Because `array_agg` does not guarantee any order by default the resulting arrays contain the right elements but not necessarily in the origin order.

Maybe this could be challenged as well. So I added a `row_number()` windowing function as a position indicator between C and D:

```
SELECT *, row_number() OVER (partition by orig, no) as position
```

Now I am able to order the arrays by doing `array_agg(single_char ORDER BY position)`. But the ordering is quiet expensive and takes another second.